# Postponing environment content

Tags: environments

I would like to create an environment `foo` and a command `\listfoo` so that:

- The content of the `foo` environment is hidden; and
- The command `\listfoo` lists all the text that was contained in a `foo` environment.

In other words, the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{foo}{% Some code here
}
{% Some code here
}
\newcommand{\listfoo}{
% Some code to list the content of the `foo` environments.
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{foo}
\bf Foo text 1
\end{foo}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{foo}
\bf Foo text 2
\end{foo}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{foo}
\bf Foo text 3
\end{foo}

\listfoo
\end{document}
```

should produce the following output:

[image: Sample]

Any suggestions for how to proceed would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `\bf` is a deprecated command. You want `\bfseries` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a macro `\foocollect` and `\NewEnviron` instead of `\newenvironment`, the `\foocollect` expands the previous `\foocollect` versions and then the local `\BODY` of the current environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{environ}


\def\foocollect{}

\NewEnviron{foo}{% Some code here
  \xdef\foocollect{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\foocollect}\par\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
}[% Some code here
]

\newcommand{\listfoo}{%
  \foocollect%
  % Some code to list the content of the `foo` environments.
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{foo}
\bfseries Foo text 1
\end{foo}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{foo}
\bfseries Foo text 2
\end{foo}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{foo}
\bfseries Foo text 3
\end{foo}

\listfoo
\end{document}
```

**Update with storing to a file instead of memory**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{morewrites}% only if you run out of filehandles    

\newwrite\collectedcontentfile

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % Automatically open the file at the beginning of the document
  \immediate\openout\collectedcontentfile=\jobname.cll
}

\NewEnviron{foo}{% Some code here
  \immediate\write\collectedcontentfile{%
    \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}^^J
  }%
}[% Some code here
]

\newcommand{\listfoo}{%
  %Closing the file
  \immediate\closeout\collectedcontentfile% 
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.cll}{}{}
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{foo}
\bfseries Foo text 1
\end{foo}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{foo}
\bfseries Foo text 2
\end{foo}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{foo}
\bfseries Foo text 3
\end{foo}

\listfoo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will do for now, though I'm having some issues with the `\foocollect` taking up too much memory.

Comment: It is possible to write the whole content to a file and input the file later on.

Comment: That's what I'm looking into and (at least currently) failing to implement. If you'd be willing to edit your answer to suggest a way of implementing that then I'd be very grateful. No worries if not.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: I think I can do that, but you should be aware that your `\listfoo` will print only the stored content up to that point of using `\listfoo`, potential later usages of the `foo` won't be catched any longer -- a better setup requires more work (but is possible too)

Comment: Thanks! That would be sufficient. All the instances of the `foo` environment will be in the main body of the text, with `\listfoo` being used in an appendix.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: See the update at the end, please. The stored file is named `\jobname.cll`, where `.cll` stands for **c**o**ll**ected, e.g. `foo.cll` if your document is called `foo.tex`

Comment: Incredible! It works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using the `scontents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scontents}
\newenvsc{foo}[store-env=foopost,print-env=false]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{foo}
\textbf{Foo text 1
\end{foo}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{foo}
\textbf{Foo text 2}
\end{foo}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{foo}
\textbf{Foo text 3}
\end{foo}
\noindent
\foreachsc[after={\\}]{foopost}
\end{document}
```

with the same proposed output:
[image: output]